# synchronising gnupg and pass

Tags: security, password, gnupg

Is it a bad idea to syncronize ~/.password-store and ~/.gnupg folders between multiple machines? I'm trying to figure out a good password management solution. If somebody were to get the contents of both folders would it somehow be easier to decrypt the stored passwords?

Comment: I put $password-store in a syncthing repo and keep separate gnupg directories on each machine. That works for me.

Comment: any reason for separate gnupg directories?

Comment: I set them up before I started using syncthing. And it is convenient to have different settings for my home and work machines.

Answer (score 0):

I often sync this two directories between computer, softlink between harddisk. Keep it same contents. **But never put them to web.**

Anyone get this, he still needs to crack your private key password. You should believe GPG.